# How to use pssh to run multiple servers with different commands?

Tags: linux, ssh, multiple-instances, parallel-processing

I need to test the distributed system with several remote servers, so I use pssh in master server to control others. Here need to run multiple server with different commands, for example

In server 201, need to run

```
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9001
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9002
```

In server 202, need to run

```
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9003
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9004
```

In server 203, need to run

```
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9005
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9006
```

...

All server information already save into hosts.txt with *username@server* format. So how to use pssh in master server to run the commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pssh` is used to run exactly the same command on different servers, your example shows that you want to run different commands on different servers (the beginning of the commands are all the same but the last number is different).

What you can do is put these commands into a script file in each of its respective servers making sure the script file is called the same on each server, then use `pssh -i -h hosts.txt script.sh`.

As an example, on server 201 put into `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9001
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9002
```

and on server 202 put into `script.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9003
java -jar test.jar 9001 **.**.**.** 9004
```

etc.

Then put `script.sh` into the $PATH of the user that will run the command or give the full path to the script, and don't forget to make the script executable on the servers.

Comment: Yes, it works well, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Also,  I have one more question, if I want to finish all process in different server, I use pnuke, but when run pssh again, it said the port (9001-900x)still be used, so how to finish the separate in different server convenient?

Comment: @Andi, please post that as a separate question.